# POSTing a new entity with a navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I'm struggling to find an example of how to create (POST) a new entity to an OData v4 service when there is a navigation property involved.

For example, let's say I have the following two models:

```
class Item
{ 
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Group Group { get; set;}
}

class Group
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If I want to create an Item which should belong to an already-defined group (with, let's say, ID = 123), then I'll POST:

```
{
  "Name": "New item",
  "Group": ???
}
```

What do I need to specify for group? I'm assuming I need to refer to it by the ID somehow. Of course, I could include the foreign key in the Item entity (GroupId) and add that. That's how I'm doing it at the moment, and it works, but is this the only way to go? What *should* I be doing? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just nest your JSON like this:

```
{
    "Name": "New item",
    "Group": 
    { 
        "Id": 5, 
        "Name": "GroupName"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this really how it works? The Group.Name property seems superfluous apart from satisfying the 'Name is required' validation. With larger entities, and more complex relationships, I can see this simple request getting huge.

Comment: [This part of the OData v4 spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata01/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata01-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc399426823) seems to relate to what I'm trying to do. Unfortunately, it doesn't actually seem to work. I've also posted about this on their codeplex discussion forum.

Comment: This is how you do it, but you don't need to include properties that already exist in the database, or properties that are not required (nullable or with default value constraints). Assuming Group has a foreign key to Item, simply adding the "Group" object in your JSON does the binding automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
POST http://host/service/Items
{"@odata.type":"#{YourSchemaNameSpace}.Item",
    "ID":111,
    "Name":"New item",
    "Groups@odata.bind":[
        "http://host/service/Groups(123)"
    ]
}
```

I tested the pattern against the sample service: http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(readwrite))/OData/OData.svc/ by requesting like this:

```
POST http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/(S(nycqcplahy351amirlopon50))/OData.svc/Products
{"@odata.type":"#ODataDemo.Product",
    "ID":111,
    "Name":"New product",
    "Categories@odata.bind":[
       "http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/(S(nycqcplahy351amirlopon50))/OData.svc/Categories(1)"
    ]
}
```

and it worked.

Comment: Thanks. Since my 'Group' isn't a collection, I adapted this to "Group@odata.bind": "http://localhost:5445/group(1)". The group URL is valid, but I'm getting an error on my item POST - 'The Group field is required'. Putting a breakpoint in my item controller shows that the Group property is indeed null. Putting another breakpoint in my group controller's GET(x) shows this isn't called either. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: @Barguast Since your "Group" isn't a collection, besides adapting to "Group@odata.bind", you also need to remove the square brackets around the reference to the group as they represent an array.

Comment: I did that - the "Group@odata.bind" property is just the URL to the group. It still doesn't seem to resolve though - the Group property in the controller just seems to come through as null.

Comment: I'm fairly sure odata.bind isn't supported in WebApi (which seems ludicrous, but anyway). Do you happen to know what that sample service is implemented in?